# Dict comprehension syntax for nested list?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can the following procedure be done using dict comprehension? `load_sample` returns a nested list the is supposed to go into a dict where the first column represent the group(1 or 2).

```
#test.txt structure 

1, 0.1, 0.2, 73
1, 0.11, 0.1, 101
2, 0.23, 0.01, 17
2, 0.12, 0.15, 23
2, 1.2, 2.30, 22



def load_sample(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as h:
        sample = [line.split(',') for line in h]
    return sample

batch = {}
d = load_sample("test.txt")
for line in d:
    key = line[0]
    if key not in batch:
        batch[key] = []
    batch[key] += [(float(line[1]), float(line[2]), float(line[3]))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
batch = {this_k:[tuple(map(float, v)) for k, *v in d if k == this_k] for this_k in set([n[0] for n in d])}
```

Output:

```
{'1': [(0.1, 0.2, 73.0), (0.11, 0.1, 101.0)], '2': [(0.23, 0.01, 17.0), (0.12, 0.15, 23.0), (1.2, 2.3, 22.0)]}
```

---

How it works:

We make a `set` of all the keys we'll want (`set([n[0] for n in d])` - the `[n[0] for n in d]` means we only have a list of the first item in each sublist) .

We then iterate over every key (`for this_k in ...`).

To make the items for the dictionary, we use `this_k:[tuple(map(float, v)) for k, *v in d if k == this_k]`

The first bit (`this_k`) tells Python the key we want (an item from our set that we're iterating over).  The second bit is what we want the value to be.

`for k, *v in d` means iterate through each item in d ( we tell Python to put the first value [ our key for the dictionary ] in `k`, to pack the other values into `v`, so we now have our key, and our value ).

Next, we check if `k` is the correct key (remember, we're creating this list of matching lines for each key in `d`).  This is done with `if k == this_k`.

Next, we create a map to convert all our values in `v` into floats (`map(float, v)`), and then we convert the map object into a `tuple` of floats.

Hopefully this makes some sense :)

Comment: Wow this was much harder than I thought, your a wizard! Do you perhaps have the time to explain what is happening in that comprehension? If not I totally understand, thank you for showing how it can be done!

Comment: It sure did, thank you for taking your time to write the explanation!